# Create lists of dictionaries from .CSV file using header words as keys

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries from my .csv file. I want to make the first row of the file the dictionary keys, and the corresponding values under them in the columns their values. This has been done successfully using a .txt file and it works perfectly. When I try to do it with the .csv format I get issues with being able to call a specific key so I don't think it's working properly.

```
newqstars = [meteor['M_P'] for meteor in kept2]

>>>KeyError: 'M_P'
```

I've been trying other methods all day such as DictReader() and csv.reader() but they don't work so I'll just ask how I can modify what I have below to be able to handle a .csv

```
def example_05(filename):


    with open(filename,'r') as file : data = file.readlines()
    header, data = data[0].split(), data[1:] 

    #................ convert each line to a dict, using header 
    # words as keys

    global kept2 
    kept2 = []

    for line in data :
        line = [to_float(term) for term in line.split()]
        kept2.append( dict( zip(header, line) ) )

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    example_05('Geminids.csv')
```

Comment: please provide sample input `summ.csv`.

Comment: [http://www.filedropper.com/geminids] okay I changed the file name in the edits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DictReader is the way to go here:

```
import csv

with open('summ.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    kept2 = [row for row in reader]
```

Comment: Simple enough then. Thank you!